# Why does Safari throw CORS error when setting base64 data on a crossOrigin = 'Anonymous' image?

Tags: javascript, image, safari, base64, cors

I'm having an issue where setting an image src (image created with `new Image`) to a base64 encoded image fails by throwing:
`Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.`

I have `image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'` already.

See the following codepen: http://codepen.io/bedeoverend/pen/aORQzg. It works in Chrome, but not in Safari. The black and white pie chart image should show up down the bottom if it worked.

Why does this happen and how can it be resolved?

UPDATE:

To clarify, I've made a more focused codepen here: http://codepen.io/bedeoverend/pen/BNGarr

It seems that setting `crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'` on an image then loading in base64 fails for Safari. Both text changes to `Worked...` on Chrome 44, but on Safari 8.0.3, the cross origin Anonymous one fails. EDIT: Also fails on Firefox 35  & 39.

So the question is essentially now, why, when an Image's crossOrigin property is set to 'Anonymous', does Safari fail to load base64 images in?

Comment: you have the issue in safari on codepen as well? I've read that safari has issues with data uri's and file:/// uris

Comment: Correct, just on safari. The codepen works fine on chrome

Comment: The problem actually comes from your `worked` function : [updated codepen](http://codepen.io/bedeoverend/pen/aORQzg) Now, as to the why? well... don't know... But anyway, it seems odd to change twice the src of an img on which you attach two different onload events.

Comment: @Kaiido see the updated codepen on my question, that should clear up the problem - the two onloads / changing the src twice, was just so I could convert it to base64 to demonstrate it failing. I've updated the question to show exactly whats going wrong: Safari seems to dislike base64 when crossOrigin is set to Anonymous

Comment: Also looks like this is a webkit bug, as seen: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=123978 which then links to other bugs, none of which seem to be resolved.

Comment: Did you looked to my updated codepen? It now works, the problem came from your `worked` function. For the img src set twice, it was just a side note and once again, even to demonstrate anything, you could just create a new img, which would avoid any unintended behaviour, such as your listeners triggering multiple times.

Comment: Your updated code only shows that when `crossOrigin` is set, Safari expect to receive an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kprwed From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image#Example_Storing_an_image_from_a_foreign_origin) *(emphasize mine)* "You **must** have a server hosting images with the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin header."

Comment: @Kaiido true, the second codepen demonstrates exactly what I want, the first had unnecessary code. So which is doing it incorrectly, Chrome or Safari? Does that mean that Chrome is in fact the one with the issue, as it allows base64 encodings, which aren't delivered from a server with the  Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Comment: none, It just means that Safari is stricter than Chrome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84420/discussion-between-bede-and-kaiido).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image#Example_Storing_an_image_from_a_foreign_origin) states that "You must have a server hosting images with the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin header."

According [to specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element:attr-img-crossorigin-5),
*<sub>emphasize mine</sub>*

> *This, unfortunately, can be used to perform a rudimentary port scan of the user's local network [...]* User agents may implement cross-origin access control policies that are **stricter** than those described above to mitigate this attack, but unfortunately such policies are typically not compatible with existing Web content."

You could simply workaround it by checking the `url` string, if it starts with `data:` then it probably won't be served with the cross origin header, then you can set the `crossOrigin` property back to `null`.