# What is the consequence of always having the crossorigin anonymous attribute on images?

Tags: image, canvas, cors

The spec for the `crossorigin` attribute on images indicates that when that attribute is omitted then the request is in a No CORS state.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#cors-settings-attribute

What is the use case for not using the `crossorigin` attribute on images?

Just for context; I am currently working with canvas with images that are both on the same domain and from other domains and I was wondering if there would be any security or other concerns with having the `crossorigin` set to `anonymous` on all images?

**Edit:** There seems to be a problem using crossorigin anonymous when using a `data:` uri on Safari ( [Why does Safari throw CORS error when setting base64 data on a crossOrigin = 'Anonymous' image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643096/why-does-safari-throw-cors-error-when-setting-base64-data-on-a-crossorigin-an) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the use case for not using the crossorigin attribute on images?

One of these is if you want to **display** an cross-origin image from a server not set-up to accept anonymous requests, and don't need to programmatically export the canvas result.
If you do set the `crossOrigin` property, then your request will simply err, you won't be able to use the resource at all.

```js
var url = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";

var cors = new Image();
cors.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
cors.onload = function(){
    console.log("your browser doesn't support crossOrigin attribute");
  };
cors.onerror = function(){
   console.log('CORS failed');
  };
cors.src = url;

var nocors = new Image();
nocors.onload = function(){
   console.log('nocors loaded');
   // we can still display it
   c.width = this.width;
   c.height = this.height;
   var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
   ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
   ctx.fillRect(0,0,this.width,this.height);
   ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
   ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
  };
nocors.src = url;
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

---

> I was wondering if there would be any security or other concerns with having the `crossorigin` set to `anonymous` on all images

There should be no real *security* issue having it set for all your images.

However, for *concerns*, there is indeed this Safari issue you mentioned, and also the fact that every request made with the crossOrigin attribute is a two steps request : First the browser makes a pre-flight request to insure that the server does agree to share it to a cross-origin server, and if so, it does finally make a get request. But this should not be a huge concern as pre-flight requests are small in data.

---

So all in all, if you are planning to programmatically export your canvas, go with all images with `crossOrigin` property, just listen for the error event in case of Safari, and you should be fine.

Comment: Will the pre-flight request be sent even if the image is on the same domain as the canvas? Or is this only the case when the image both has the `crossorigin` attribute, and is actually a cross origin resource?